# Android - how to set app name dynamically

Tags: android

Is there a way to set the name of my app dynamically?  I've got an app that connects to a web service to get some data (application name, DBName, DBVersion, etc.) and I want to be able to set the name of the app to whatever the web service returns.  I tried:

```
R.string.app_name = "New App Name";
```

but app_name is an integer, not a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to change the actual app name or just whatever is showing on the title bar/action bar?

Comment: just change whatever the titlebar/action bar reads....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call below code to change the title displaying on Title bar.

```
setTitle("New Title");
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm fairly new to Android programming and still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @Yugandhar Babu Is it possible to change the app name, logo name on runtime??